# Why does git remote show two commits for the same tag?

Tags: git, git-rebase, git-remote, git-tag

When I check the tags for a remote git repository using `git ls-remote --tags origin` I see the following:

```
0a8e26c20   refs/tags/v1.0
acd5c5c8e   refs/tags/v1.0^{}
```

I rebased a few commits earlier in the history and suspect that explains what is going on here.

When I check the commit log, I see that `0a8e26c20` in fact doesn't exist. However I can successfully checkout that commit but end up with commit `acd5c5c8e` (as if one links to the other).

Could someone confirm that the rebase caused this and (if it's possible) tell me how to fix it?

Thanks!
Arlo